# Why could the subclass method throw error

Tags: java, throw

I try this code, The compiler gives no problems, I wonder that the validate method in Bar could throw nothing ,AssertionError, or subclass of AssertionError. but in the code Error is a superclass of AssertionError, so why no problems occues

```
abstract class Foo {
abstract void validate() throws AssertionError;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
void  validate() throws  Error  {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The rules for the compiler you describe apply to checked exceptions. Checked exceptions are `Throwable`, `Exception` and all exceptions that extend `Exception`, excluding `RuntimeException` and it's descendents. Both `AssertionError` and `Error` extend `Error`, which makes them unchecked. This means you can throw them anywhere without the compiler complaining. This last behaviour also applies to `RuntimeException`, like `NullPointerException` for instance.

The full tree is like this:

```
Throwable (checked)
-Exception (checked)
--RuntimeException (unchecked)
-Error (unchecked)
```